# Redirect incoming url to a subdir [htaccess]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm struggling with this from hours...

what i have is a domain with (virtual) subdir based on languages so domain.com/en for example.

The point is that it is indexed in goggle and this structure is changed since few days, so old links points to domain.com/postname (giving a 404)

I'm trying to do a redirect so the domain.com/postname will redirect to domain.com/en/postname

but my tryings are with a loop error like domain.com/en/en/en/en/postname and similar.
my last trying is with this code but it seems it doenst work either:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/([^/]+)$ http://domain.com/en/$1
```

any help guys?
THanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^en/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule before it that limits to files not having the /en/ directory, not sure of the exact code, but something like:

```
RewriteRule !/en/(.*)
```

Comment: it will go in loop /en/en/en/en etc ;(

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Try this (using mod_rewrite)

Comment: tried with IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !/en/(.*)
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/([^/]+)$ http://domain/en/$1
</IfModule>
but it gives a internal error